# Is it bad practice to shift traffic distributions for test experiences during the run of a test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, experiment-design

I have recently come across a testing design that Adobe uses in their "Adobe Target" tool that they call "Auto-Allocation".  Here is their article on the test design.

https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/target/target/automated_traffic_allocation.html

I am rather dubious of this testing procedure, as the idea of shifting the sampling rate for each experience during the test seems like it would causes issues with accuracy and validity of the test.  Particularly, if you are changing today's experience based on yesterday's results would seem to create a correlation between each day's observations.  Adobe claims that they correct for any issues with this design by using the Bernstein Inequality to compute their confidence intervals (found in the "The Solution: Auto-Allocate" portion of the linked article).  They only provide a link to a Wikipedia article, that does not seem to provide satisfactory support to their claim.

Does anyone have any resources or knowledge to share around this testing design?  Is the method Adobe uses the proper correction?  Is their a different correction that should be used for this test?